# Unable to update packages in Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS

Tags: server

Hello I recently installed Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS and cannot get it to update the packages at all with the apt-get update and upgrade command.  I am new to this and am not sure if the wifi is setup correctly.  The error messages seem to point that it is not looking at the right server. Hope this helps
-Thanks

Comment: You need to post the commands you ran and the error messages. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Sorry, So basicaly I am getting the error message " Temporary failure resolving "us.archive.Ubuntu.com" " on both commands.  Also failed to fetch shows up before the upgrade command results.  I do not think I am behind a proxy

Comment: Commands I ran were sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: @user535733 or name resolution is not working. Is `ping -c 5 google.com` working?

Comment: When I used ping on google I get the message "Ping: Unknown Host google.com" and I do not know how to change the mirror.  I am very new to server stuff so I am sorry for my confusion.

Comment: So it's not just Ubuntu mirrors? ALL network activity is failing? (being new is irrelevant - we were all new once)

Comment: It looks that way